# Agent VMs of different sizes in Azure Container Service

Tags: azure, azure-container-service

Is there any way to have VMs of different sizes in the private agents pool of an Azure Container Service (ACS)? I would like to support use cases where some services require compute intensive servers and others (e.g databases) memory intensive servers.

An acceptable solution could be to add multiple virtual machines scale sets (vmss) as private agents pools and each one of them have VMs of different sizes since a vmss supports one size of VM. Is such a feature supported in ACS?

A workaround could be to have different sizes of VMs in the public and private agent pools. However, this is not a best practice since public agents pool should be used to host services that are exposed publicly (e.g marathon-lb). Also, it limits the options to just two pools.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is coming and if you need them today you can use ACS Engine (the open source code behind ACS). See examples at https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/tree/master/examples/largeclusters

Comment: Thank you for the response. The solution that I found is to deploy another vmss with private agents and the size of vm that I need. I exported the template of my current infrastructure from Azure, added the new vmss and reposted the template. The resources that already existed were left untouched (as stated in [Azure RM documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy-rest)) and the new vmss was created.

Comment: That is essentially what the ACS Engine does. If you get the opportunity to move your cluster to an ACS Engine cluster I would recommend doing so since most features in there will eventually make it into the SLA backed ACS and thus you will have a better long term experience.